# How to retrieve data between from date to system date using excel VBA (Automation Error)

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to extract a data from an Excel through different Excel using `ADODB.Connection` but when I am trying to retrieve data between from date to system date I am getting an automation error in Excel.

I have checked various articles but I'm unable to validate those condition because I don't have SQL Server so I am directly putting into Excel coding but again same error I am getting.

Please help......

```
Sub get_data()

Dim strSQL As String
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim DBPath As String
Dim sconnect As String

DBPath = "\\abc\Quality Report.xlsx"


sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

cnn.Open sconnect


strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Error_Log$] WHERE "

    If cboprocess.Text <> "" Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " [Process]='" & cboprocess.Text & "'"
    End If

    If cboaudittype.Text <> "" Then
        If cboprocess.Text <> "" Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " AND [Audit_Type]='" & cboaudittype.Text & "'"
        Else
            strSQL = strSQL & " [Audit_Type]='" & cboaudittype.Text & "'"
        End If
    End If

    If cbouser1.Text <> "" Then
        If cboprocess.Text <> "" Or cboaudittype.Text <> "" Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " AND [User_Name]='" & cbouser1.Text & "'"
        Else
            strSQL = strSQL & " [User_Name]='" & cbouser1.Text & "'"
        End If
    End If

    If cborptmgr.Text <> "" Then
        If cboprocess.Text <> "" Or cboaudittype.Text <> "" Or cbouser1.Text <> "" Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " AND [Reporting_Manager]='" & cborptmgr.Text & "'"
        Else
            strSQL = strSQL & " [Reporting_Manager]='" & cborptmgr.Text & "'"
        End If
    End If

    If cbotranstyp.Text <> "" Then
        If cboprocess.Text <> "" Or cboaudittype.Text <> "" Or cbouser1.Text <> "" Or cborptmgr.Text <> "" Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " AND [Transaction_Type]='" & cbotranstyp.Text & "'"
        Else
            strSQL = strSQL & " [Transaction_Type]='" & cbotranstyp.Text & "'"
        End If
    End If

    If cboperiod.Text <> "" Then
        If cboprocess.Text <> "" Or cboaudittype.Text <> "" Or cbouser1.Text <> "" Or cborptmgr.Text <> "" _
        Or cbotranstyp.Text <> "" Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " AND [Period]='" & cboperiod.Text & "'"
        Else
            strSQL = strSQL & " [Period]='" & cboperiod.Text & "'"
        End If
    End If

    If cbolocation.Text <> "" Then
        If cboprocess.Text <> "" Or cboaudittype.Text <> "" Or cbouser1.Text <> "" Or cborptmgr.Text <> "" _
        Or cbotranstyp.Text <> "" Or cboperiod.Text <> "" Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " AND [Location]='" & cbolocation.Text & "'"
        Else
            strSQL = strSQL & " [Location]='" & cbolocation.Text & "'"
        End If
    End If

    If cbofatnfat.Text <> "" Then
        If cboprocess.Text <> "" Or cboaudittype.Text <> "" Or cbouser1.Text <> "" Or cborptmgr.Text <> "" _
        Or cbotranstyp.Text <> "" Or cboperiod.Text <> "" Or cbolocation.Text <> "" Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " AND [Fatal_NonFatal]='" & cbofatnfat.Text & "'"
        Else
            strSQL = strSQL & " [Fatal_NonFatal]='" & cbofatnfat.Text & "'"
        End If
    End If

    If cbostatus.Text <> "" Then
        If cboprocess.Text <> "" Or cboaudittype.Text <> "" Or cbouser1.Text <> "" Or cborptmgr.Text <> "" _
        Or cbotranstyp.Text <> "" Or cboperiod.Text <> "" Or cbolocation.Text <> "" Or cbofatnfat.Text <> "" Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " AND [Remarks]='" & cbostatus.Text & "'"
        Else
            strSQL = strSQL & " [Remarks]='" & cbostatus.Text & "'"
        End If
    End If

    If txtfromauditdt.Text <> "" Then
        If cboprocess.Text <> "" Or cboaudittype.Text <> "" Or cbouser1.Text <> "" Or cborptmgr.Text <> "" _
        Or cbotranstyp.Text <> "" Or cboperiod.Text <> "" Or cbolocation.Text <> "" Or cbofatnfat.Text <> "" _
        Or cbostatus.Text <> "" Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " AND [Audit_Date] BETWEEN '" & txtfromauditdt.Text & "' AND GETDATE()"
        Else
            strSQL = strSQL & " [Audit_Date] BETWEEN '" & txtfromauditdt.Text & "' AND GETDATE()"
        End If
    End If


Debug.Print strSQL

    Set rs.ActiveConnection = cnn
    rs.Open strSQL, cnn

 Sheet1.Range("A42").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
cnn.Close

End Sub
```

Below is debug print from strsql

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Error_Log$] 
WHERE [Audit_Date] BETWEEN '16-Nov-2015' AND getdate()
```

Error screenshot

[image]

Comment: I don't think GETDATE() is available outside of SQL server.  Try hard-coding the date in the sql instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out the error cause...

Actually the error was because of the quotes `'13-nov-15'` which I was using in coding but the same was replacing after with `#13-nov-15#`. It worked.

As per the @Williams answer's there was a only one correction made for another date but for parameter date the quotes was coming but now its working cool. Thanks to Tim Williams..helps a lot....

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is GetDate()

Your approach to building the WHERE clause can also be much simpler:

```
Sub get_data()

Dim strSQL As String, strWhere As String
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim DBPath As String
Dim sconnect As String

    DBPath = "\\abc\Quality Report.xlsx"
    sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

    cnn.Open sconnect

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Error_Log$] WHERE "
    strWhere = ""

    BuildWhere strWhere, cboprocess.Text, "Process"
    BuildWhere strWhere, cboaudittype.Text, "Audit_Type"
    BuildWhere strWhere, cbouser1.Text, "User_Name"
    BuildWhere strWhere, cborptmgr.Text, "Reporting_Manager"
    BuildWhere strWhere, cbotranstyp.Text, "Transaction_Type"
    BuildWhere strWhere, cboperiod.Text, "Period"
    BuildWhere strWhere, cbolocation.Text, "Location"
    BuildWhere strWhere, cbofatnfat.Text, "Fatal_NonFatal"
    BuildWhere strWhere, cbostatus.Text, "Remarks"

    If txtfromauditdt.Text <> "" Then
       strWhere = strWhere & IIf(strWhere <> "", " AND ", "") & "[Audit_Date] BETWEEN '" & _
                  txtfromauditdt.Text & "' AND #" & Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# "
    End If

    strSQL = strSQL & strWhere

    Debug.Print strSQL

    Set rs.ActiveConnection = cnn
    rs.Open strSQL, cnn

    Sheet1.Range("A42").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    cnn.Close

End Sub

Sub BuildWhere(ByRef strWhere As String, v As String, fld As String)
    If v <> "" Then
        strWhere = strWhere & IIf(strWhere <> "", " AND ", "") & _
                    "[" & fld & "] = '" & v & "'"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the revert @Tim Williams, this help me little but still I am getting an automation error. Will update the error screenshot in thread

Answer (score 0):

You surrounded the first text date with single quotes `'`, this will make it a string. You need to use the number sign `#` instead, like this:

```
Or cbostatus.Text <> "" Then
    strSQL = strSQL & " AND [Audit_Date] BETWEEN #" & txtfromauditdt.Text & "# AND GETDATE()"
Else
    strSQL = strSQL & " [Audit_Date] BETWEEN #" & txtfromauditdt.Text & "# AND GETDATE()"
End If
```